# What is the kernel parameter to decrypt partition other than root?

Tags: encryption

In order for the bootloader to decrypt the root filesystem you just need the parameters `cryptdevice=/dev/sda1:crypt root=/dev/mapper/crypt`. What would be the parameter for other filessystems than root so I am prompted for multiple device to decrypt (the equivalent of `root=` for non root fs).

EDIT : If my encrypted data partition is /dev/sda2, will adding /dev/mapper/cryptsda2 in fstab be enough to tell the system to uncrypt /dev/sda2 first ?

Comment: In theory an OS does not need this capability, as it can do this one the system is up. (I don't know about the reality of it though).

Comment: Be careful: Ensure that key is not stored with computer (use passphrase and/or removable key). If your computer is left where it could otherwise be compromised (if it was not encrypted), then consider if compromised, if you ever unlock it afterwards.

Comment: Guessing based on https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Dm-crypt/System_configuration `cryptdevice=/dev/sda2:somename` might create `/dev/mapper/somename` which you could mount

Comment: @ilkkachu you're right, cryptsetup as kernel parameter will decrypt the encrypted device and fstab will mount that automatically. I thought i had to find the equivalent of `root=`

Comment: If you get no answers maybe this can work instead: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23451824/363028